# Multiple Threads Trying to write on the same No-Sql Datastore at the same time

Tags: database, multithreading, concurrency, nosql, java.util.concurrent

We have a internal no-sql datastore for our company. I provides Key-Value storage. The value is of JSON format. I will refer it as XYZ DataStore.

Problem Statement:

I have an application which is spawning 10-15 threads at a time. Each thread is responsible for writing to the same XYZ concurrently. Though the records being PUT, are different, (meaning different Key). The XYZ Rest Client created is singleton, meaning all the threads are using one singleton client. (I am using spring beans to create singleton client).

Observation: Only one thread is able to put the records in XYZ. The other threads are not able to write to sable at all, **not even after a delay time.**

How can I handle this concurrent writing to XYZ? What is the preferred way?

I can achieve it by following:

- Implement Lock on the PUT API on my end and even if concurrent
  threads are attempting to write, with a single thread, it should be
  able to wait until the lock is released.

  - I am not sure how to implement this. If anyone has pointers, it will be great.
- The above are like the producer threads. I can create one consumer thread. The producer thread would write this record to be put in a
  Queue and the consumer thread would be reading it one by one and
  updating it.

  - Here, I will be using java.util.concorrent. BlockingQueue to read and write in a queue, being used by consumer and producer threads. Is this the correct way?

Can anyone suggest me which is the best way to do it?

BTW, the application is built in Java, using spring framework.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Even singleton as well ensure you are not sharing anything across threads and each method in that class is separate only then you can very well set that as singleton and dont worry about the blocking since its going to be a method call so each thread will simply call that method. thats it. Here you know each transaction is failed or not based on the method response so based on that you decide whether the transaction is success or re-initiate it for later. No delay required.

In Queuing system you can probably consider DeQueue its much better on in concurrent package. see some examples and implement it. This is as well effective but here you are sharing the queue across multiple threads. You wont feel that slowness but sharing is happening here. Here is there is no such transaction is passed for the pushed values or not. One thing we can do it after successful only we can dequeue the value otherwise just do the look alone. if keep on fails move to separate queue for later use. this is one more pardon for us. No delay required.